# Composer path for PhpStorm

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Composer in WSL and it is working correctly with bash, 
but now it seems I need the path for Composer in PhpStorm, 
or is there some other way to access Composer remotely (like PHP) in PhpStorm?

Comment: Remote Composer is not supported in PhpStorm:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23544
Also I suppose there would be an issue with paths, as they're different in WSL, like /mnt/c/whatever.
What's wrong with having Composer installed on your Windows machine?

Comment: if i install composer on windows i must install php too, So what do I need to WSL?!

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing, only local Composer installations are supported, and WSL is a virtual machine.